# How to write special symbols (arrows and all keys on keyboard) in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, special-characters

I am writing a code to do actions on events on keys on keyboard.Instead of checking keycodes on events , I want to map respective symbols to keys. I am trying to map each key symbol with its keycode . 
Something like done in Keybinding.js -> https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4444952/.

But I am not able to enter symbols in Javascript. I copies some part of this Keybinding.js but its showing symbols like 'â†' for all.

Can anyone help me about how can I write such symbols in Javascript.

Comment: This will help http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

Comment: I cant see escape code for left,up,right,down arrows.
How to write following code in JS

d3.select('body').call(d3.keybinding()
    .on('←', move(-2, 0))
    .on('↑', move(0, -2))
    .on('→', move(2, 0))
    .on('↓', move(0, 2)));

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a9/index.htm
and do it like 
    var Omega = '\u03A9';

Unicode character can be done like this.

Comment: Aha..Check this http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the JavaScript file as UTF-8 encoded with BOM (using whatever tools your text editor has for specifying the character encoding). The BOM (Byte Order Mark) makes browsers recognize the file as UTF-8 encoded even when the encoding is not specified in HTTP headers (and, except for IE, even against HTTP headers).

An alternative is to use escapes like `'\u21e7'` for `'⇧'`, but the code becomes difficult to write and read. This, however, needs to be done in the unlikely event that your server sends HTTP headers that specify the encoding as something else than UTF-8 and you cannot change this (and you need to support IE).

Comment: Thanks , this atleast show symbol when instected in debuuger. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use this HTML code
https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm
put the code in the span tage
For example :

```
<span>&#33;</span>
```